# Keydown / Keyup gets called 7 times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keydown, keyup

I'm currently building an AngularJS website with a game. Here I want to use the keyboard to resume/pause and control the game. The code I have to add the eventlistener is the following:

```
$window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
     if ($scope.gameState.playing) {
        for (var control in controls) {
            if (controls.LEFT.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
                gameEngine.startLeft();
            } else if (controls.RIGHT.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
                gameEngine.startRight();
            } else if (controls.POWERJUMP.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
                gameEngine.powerJump();
            } else if (controls.PAUSE.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
                $scope.pauseGame();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The content of the function isn't very important, but my problem is that it gets called 7 times every time I press a key. The same is with `keyup`. However fast or slow I press it.

```
var GameApp = angular.module('GameApp', []);
GameApp.controller('GameController', function($scope, $timeout, $window)
```

The above code is how I create the Angular app and controller with the $window argument.

I couldn't find a solution for this. I hope anyone knows why that's happening.

Comment: Where do you call the $window.addEventListener? Inside what controller? Is it inside a directive? How many times is this directive initialised? It would help to know the markup of your app in order to help you

Comment: Also keep in mind that if the $window.addEventListener is inside GameController, if you have routing it is possible for for the GameController to be initialized many times, readding the event listener each time.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess: is the event handler registered 7 times?

To check do something like:

```
$window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.iAmNotAlone) {
    throw new Error('Oh dear!');
  }

  e.iAmNotAlone = true;

  /* for control in control thingy goes here */
});
```

Are you setting this up in the singleton part of a service or in some sort of controller (which will be recreated every time and could explain this behaviour) ?

Comment: It never gets thrown. So I guess that's not the problem.

Comment: Still, you'll probably want to move that `addEventListener` out of the controller and into a (singleton) service. The event listener is otherwise leaking and recreated every time the controller is recreated.

Comment: I'm only calling the controller once, but I will still do it. When I got the time. Thank you